# How scheduling algorithm determine the type of process (I/o, CPU bound)

Tags: linux, unix, operating-system, scheduling, scheduler

I am reading through the scheduling algorithms and wondered how an scheduling algorithm decide whether the process is `cpu bound` or `io bound` and takeup the decision accordingly? For example, in the `multilevel feedback queue` implementation , it mentions that it give preferences to the short job, i/o bound. My question is how will it determine it ?

[reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilevel_feedback_queue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Linux 2.6 a process is considered to be interactive if its dynamic priority is greater than its static priority.

Linux updates the priority of every process dynamically according to its **average waiting time**. (Without going into the exact calculations and functions).

We'd expect `cpu bound` process to have a low average waiting time. In contrast we'd expect an `I/O bound` process to have a high waiting time.